# C warning implicit declaration of function 'exit'

Tags: c, gcc-warning

This is my warning.

```
implicit declaration of function 'exit'
```

How i can remove it.

i am using linux & gcc compiler.

Comment: `man 3 exit` will show you the header to include.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Add:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

to the top of your program.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: In my program,  I have not used `#include <stdlib.h>` and I am getting this warning only when I use `-Wall` option. Otherwise the program compiles fine and executable runs properly. This means that gcc is somehow able to link to the file without my including it. How is that happening?

Comment: @eSKay: Implicit declarations are *permitted* in C unless you use the `-Wmissing-protypes` warning switch (which is turned on by `-Wall`).

Answer (score 12):

Do you have this preprocessor?  If not, add it.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Answer (score 2):

exit() is a library function, the respecive prototypes are present in  the **stdlib.h** header file, inoder to call the process to specified code for exit function, you need to attach the as **#include stdlib.h** header in your program. that is the reason we  should add the stdlib.h header. eventhough you can run the program, but it shows the warning message like below:

```
warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
```

but, this kind of program not recommended, we need to take care of what we are given in the program,be cautious. 
warning may leads runtime error.